# How to filter on individuals in SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, protege

I'm new to this language and queries. In Protege, I am using the PROV ontology and FOAF and I also added a few of my own instances and classes. With this ontology, I am trying to map the process of a medical research. With the SPARQL queries, I want to quickly retrieve important information about the process.

I have multiple questions:
[image]

Looking at the query above, the output makes sense to me. On the left are some research papers (MetaAnalysis belongs to the class MetaAnalysisPaper and Paper2 belongs to the class Research) and on the right are some names that are part of the class Author.

1. How do I filter on MetaAnalysis? So that only 'MetaAnalysis wasAttributedTo (name of author)' relations show up, and not Paper2.
2. How do I filter on Author, let's say for example Biederman? So that only the relation 'MetaAnalysis wasAttributedTo Biederman' shows up.

The following is an individual:
[image]

I also have the CImin individual, also belonging to the ConfidenceInterval class, it has the same wasGeneratedBy relation, the value is 0.12 and defined in the same way as CImax.

3. I want an output that gives me the value (0.39) of the CImax and the value (0.12) of the CImin. Is it possible to get just both these outputs with one query? What would this query look like? And if it isn't possible with one query, what would the query for just the value of CImax look like?

Thank you in advance. My Turtle file was very, very big, so I decided to not upload it here, but if it's necessary, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I filter on MetaAnalysis? So that only 'MetaAnalysis wasAttributedTo (name of author)' relations show up, and not Paper2.

You can do this using [filter expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#expressions). For example, in your case you could add something like:

```
FILTER(?property = lol:MetaAnalysis)
```

I say "something like" this because in your screenshots, it's not clear what namespace the resource `MetaAnalysis` is in. I'm *guessing* it's the default ontology namespace created by Protege (abbreviated to `lol` going by the first image), but you may need to double-check that.

> How do I filter on Author, let's say for example Biederman? So that only the relation 'MetaAnalysis wasAttributedTo Biederman' shows up.

Same idea, just different variable and value:

```
FILTER(?object = lol:Biederman)
```

(this is assuming that `Biederman` is a resource URI in your data, and not a literal value - it's not clear from your screenshots)

Put either filter condition in the WHERE clause (after the statement pattern) and you should be good to go.

> I want an output that gives me the value (0.39) of the CImax and the value (0.12) of the CImin. Is it possible to get just both these outputs with one query? What would this query look like? And if it isn't possible with one query, what would the query for just the value of CImax look like?

Yes, that's possible, in multiple ways. One thing you could do is create a SPARQL query that gets *all* individuals of type `ConfidenceInterval` (something like `?ci rdf:type lol:ConfidenceInterval .`) and grab their values (e.g `?ci lol:value ?value`). Combine both patterns in a single SPARQL query to get all things that match both patterns. Add additional filters and patterns as you go to make your query more specific, as needed.

More generally speaking: this is really basic SPARQL that you're asking for here. I'd recommend you do a tutorial, there's several really good ones available online, a quick Google will sort you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first two answers work, however the last answer (question 3) doesn't work. `SELECT ?ci ?value
 WHERE {?ci rdf:type lol:ConfidenceInterval .
  ?ci lol:value ?value .
}` gives no output. When I delete the line `?ci lol:value ?value` I get CImax and CImin under ´ci´ but the ´value´ tab remains empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Zzz it's impossible that the query does not work as long as your data really fits the query patterns. Is the `value` property your own property with the same namespace?

Comment: @UninformedUser I totally forgot that the data property 'value' belongs to the PROV ontology. The domain of value is 'entity' (no range given), and ConfidenceInterval is a subclass of 'entity'. However, when I use the code `SELECT ?ci ?value 
WHERE {?ci rdf:type lol:ConfidenceInterval .
  ?ci prov:value ?value . }`, my output is still empty. I also tried using <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#value> instead of prov:value, but that also gave an empty output.

Comment: @Zzz that's impossible if you're using the correct namespace and the data is what you have shown on your screenshot. `SELECT ?ci ?value WHERE {?ci rdf:type lol:ConfidenceInterval . ?ci  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#value> ?value . }` can't be empty or you data is wrong.  Copy and past my query and try again. If that does not work, please post the data here or share it.

Comment: @UninformedUser I have no clue where I went wrong, but after restarting the program, pasting your query in SPARQL and running it, it works now. It also works with prov:value. Thank you for your help!